# How do I solve my first python program

Tags: python

I am a rookie in programing, so I needs some help with my codes!

I can't run the following program correctly, I get the type error
I just want to know why it doesn't work. 
Thank you in advance!

```
def main():
  celsius = input("celsius: ")
  farhrenheit = (celsius * ( 9/5 ) + 32)
  print (farhrenheit)
main()
```

it pomps out this:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: `input()` returns a string, not a number.

Comment: So, use the code `celsius = float(input("celsius: ")` to turn it into a floating point number

Answer (score 0):

Add a float function.

```
celsius = float(input("celsius: "))
```